# Is there a physical meaning of ranking in differential algebra?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The main stone in the [Ritt's Algorithm](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&lr=&id=g87NBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA219&dq=Implementing%20Ritt%27s%20algorithm%20of%20differential%20algebra&ots=LQWEhw1x3h&sig=_j5lRta-hNsDQpLVDl1LB5XwJRE#v=onepage&q=Implementing%20Ritt%27s%20algorithm%20of%20differential%20algebra&f=false) from differential algebra is ranking.

If we consider an example of a differential polynomial with two variables $x$ and $y$. Then how can we say $x$ is ranked higher then $y$? What does this physically mean if this was representing a physical system?